# Best way to add environment variables to an Angular app during Google Build?

Tags: angular, environment-variables, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am new to Angular and deployment in general.

I use Google Build and Google Run to build and deploy an Angular app. I've set up a trigger for continuous development with a Cloud Build configuration file (yaml). When I push my code to the GitHub repo the build activates.

In the Angular app I use environment variables using the environments directory and the environment.ts and environment.prod.ts files. I believe this is the standard way to use environment variables in Angular.

Of course, for security reasons, I don't push the environment files to the GitHub repo. So during the build I get the error 'cannot find module 'environments'. What is the best way in my case to add the environment variables to the build?

I've read that a possible solution is to add an extra 'environment.template.ts' file to the environments directory that uses placeholder values that you push to the GitHub repo. Then when using the `ng build` command, you can pass environment variables using the `--configuration` flag and specify the corresponding environment file: for example production build: `ng build --configuration=production`. But I can't seem to get the last step right.

How can I add environment variables step by step?